# Google Cloud Functions source not following the last commit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-source-repos

Yesterday I've noticed a weird behavior on Google Cloud Functions. I push to Cloud Source Repository, then trigger a deploy from the UI, however, it doesn't get resolved to the last commit. Up till yesterday it was working as expected and the source of the function was always resolved to the last commit. Is anyone else facing this behavior?

It can be overcome by pushing with a tag and setting the Cloud Function source to look for that tag.

Comment: How do you know that isn't the latest commit? In addition, are you sure that you haven't function deployment issue?

Comment: I can see the last commit id in Cloud Source repository. There isn't any issue in the log, it says the deployment has been successful.

Comment: I have the same issue when I deploy the function in the UI, however I tried to do the same with gcloud and it worked, strange behavior